# Fix remove unused javascript in shopify that are coming from youtube video like base.js etc

Tags: shopify

I want to remove the unused javascript that is coming from youtube. Please check screenshot below. It's just a simple technique to remove this but I can't find how to fix this. I have already added lazyload to youtube video. Please help me to fix this. I will be very thankful to all of you.[please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K5Ok.jpg)

Comment: You load the iframe on demand or use any 3rd party lazy loading JS lib to achieve it.